# How to use etherscan.io api with ethereum wallet

Tags: android, ethereum

I would like to integrate etherscan.io API with my android project but I don't know how to map ethereum wallet with etherscan.io API. I have created a test ethereum wallet and made some transactions in the wallet.

I created the API key on etherscan.io account and have the address on my ethereum wallet but when I am using etherscan.io API to get the balance for that address, it is returning 0 even it has some balance.

Can anyone guide me on how to integrate etherscan.io API?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the API URL for the correct network?

Main NET:
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&tag=latest&apikey=***

Ropsten: 
https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&tag=latest&apikey=***

Rinkeby:
https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&tag=latest&apikey=***

P.s.  I think using the standard JSON-RPC will be the best practice.
You will not be bound to the etherscan API and will be able to use any open (for example "infura.io") or your node.

For development android-app it is possible to use library web3j